# removeRow() not removing rows as expected in phpExcel

Tags: php, loops, foreach, phpexcel

I tried removing blank rows [actually rows that doesn't meet criteria].
This is what I tried:

```
if(null !== ($this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus')))
{
    $userStatus =  $this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus');
}

$rowID = 5;
foreach ($results as $result) 
   {
     if($result['status'] == $userStatus)
     {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowID, $result['fullname']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowID, $result['checkin_date']);
     }
   else
     {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($rowID);
     }
     $rowID++;
   }
```

But still I'm getting blank rows:

```
       A   |  B   |  C  |  D
  1        |      |     |
  .
  .
  174      |      |     |
  175      |      |     |
  176      |      |     |
  177      |      |     |
  178 John |  2014| xyz | dfdf
  179 Jack |  2015| jkl | dfdf
  180      |      |     |
  .
  .
```

How do I get rid of those empty rows? Row numbers don't really matter, all I need to do is get rid of those blank rows. Please help me with this...Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still incrementing rowID that's why you've got empty rows

```
if(null !== ($this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus')))
{
    $userStatus =  $this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus');
}

$rowID = 5;
foreach ($results as $result) 
   {
     if($result['status'] == $userStatus)
     {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowID, $result['fullname']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowID, $result['checkin_date']);
     }
   else
     {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($rowID);
        continue;
     }
     $rowID++;
   }
```

Comment: works well :) and also row numbers are taken care of.. thanks a lot :)